# Assign variable identifier in loop and echo its value

Tags: shell-script, variable, arithmetic

I hope this question is not a duplicate because I've been trying various ways to solve this problem  but couldn't find any solution.

I have a for loop in which I'd like to store a command output into a variable whose name is changing every round and would like to do echo and do further operations on these variables, something like this:

```
for i in `seq 1 $netsize`
do
    echo "node$i: "
    export Bal$i=$(node$i getbalance | bc)  #PIPE TO BC SINCE getbalance RETURNS FLOAT TYPE VALUE
    echo $Bal$i | tee -a <text-file path>   #THIS GIVES ME ONLY 1,2,... NOT THE getbalance VALUE!!!
...
```

Further I'd like to take node1's getbalance and divide it by sum of total balance of all nodes. So I did this but I get a syntax error:

```
...
echo "$Bal1/($Bal1+$Bal2+$Bal3+$Bal4+$Bal5+$Bal6+$Bal7+$Bal8+$Bal9)" | bc >> <text-file path> #HERE; I DO THIS FOR A netsize OF 9 NODES ...
```

How could I solve this second problem for an arbitrary netsize?

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer if you give some context to your question: what is `getbalance`? what does `node$i getbalance` return, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a bash array.  I would save the values into an index array with something like:

```
declare -a bal
for i in `seq 1 $netsize`
do
    echo "node$i: "
    bal[$i]=$(node$i getbalance | bc) //PIPE TO BC SINCE getbalance RETURNS FLOAT TYPE VALUE

    echo ${bal[$i]} # should be the right value
done
```

then to put together the command you want to echo to `bc` we'll play a little game with a subshell and `IFS` like

```
denominator=$(IFS=+; echo "${bal[*]:2}")
equation="${bal[1]}/($denominator)"
```

Setting `IFS=+` will make it so the fields in the array are separated by `+` when we echo them in the next statement.  The `${bal[*]:2}` accesses all of the elements of the `bal` array (that's the `${bal[*]}` part).  In this case though, we know element number 1 is something we want to skip, since we're going to use that in the numerator of the equation, so we add `:2` to take from index `2` on.  So `${bal[*]:2}` gives us all of the elements of the array `bal` index 2 and up.

You can see more about bash array slicing [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335815/how-to-slice-an-array-in-bash) or more [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#getting_values)

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm wondering what _${bal[*]:2}_ means!? Setting the "+" as IFS doesn't do anything, right?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi I just updated my answer to include more explanation, the `IFS=+` is actually pretty important here since that's what will put the `+` between all the array elements so you can use it in your `bc` command

Answer (score 0):

```
netsize=$somenum
(   echo  scale=\(2;  set --                           ### set scale; clear args
    while [ "$#" -lt "$netsize" ]                      ### counts up to $netsize
    do    set "$@" "bal$(($#+1))"                      ### saves arg count as bal$#+1
    ###   I do the below because you don't say what 
    ###   node$# getbalance does. Here it's random.
          eval "node$#(){ "':& x=${!%??} y=${!#"$x"}
                               echo "$x.$y/'"$#\"; }"  ### fakes a node$#() function
          printf "%bbal$#=%b" ');"' '";' \(            ### );"bal$#=";(bal$#=
          "node$#" getbalance                          ### $x.$y/$#\n
    done; printf %b+ ");($1/($@))\c"                   ### );(bal1/(bal1+...bal$netsize))
) | paste -sd\\0 | bc                                  ### removes all \newlines but last
```

So it's not at all easy to tell what you're trying to do, but one thing I noticed it that you seem to think you need to call a separate `bc` for every arithmetic evaluation. The opposite is by far the more convenient way to go - `bc` is an interactive program, besides being a fully-fledged scripting language all its own. It will set and store variable values for the duration of its uptime - and so rather than trying to store all of that information in the shell, just pipe out your equations and let `bc` store their values for you.

For example:

```
{ echo 'x=1+2'; echo '"x=";x'; }| bc
```

...which prints...

```
x=3
```

Because first `bc` evaluates `x` to equal `1+2`, then it prints the arbitrary string `"x="` to stdout, and last it is asked to print `x`'s value, and so it does.

The script above does virtually the same thing. For each iteration `bal` is incremented by one. And it prints out to `bc`:

```
);"bal$#=";(bal$#=$!/$#\n
```

...and then when it has incremented `$#` to match `$netsize` it prints *(given an example `$netsize` of 10)*...

```
(bal1/(bal1+bal2+bal3+bal4+bal5+bal6+bal7+bal8+bal9+bal10))
```

None of those values are saved at all in the shell - `bc` remembers them all, though. And when you enclose a `bc` expression in `(` parens `)` it is evaluated *and* printed.

I use `paste -sd\\0` to remove all `\n`ewlines because I don't know what `"node$#" getbalance` should do, but I assume it will follow its output with a `\n`ewline, and `(bal1=`*`node$# getbalance's output`*`\n)` is a syntax error. So I clear them all and separate the expressions with `;` semicolons instead *(which I am rather hoping is not a char `node$# getbalance` will print)*. To get a clear picture of what the whole script prints, you can replace the `bc` at the tail w/ `tr \; \\n`.

Here, for example, is what it will print if `netsize=10`:

```
scale=(2)
"bal1="
(bal1=261.40/1)
"bal2="
(bal2=261.41/2)
"bal3="
(bal3=261.42/3)
"bal4="
(bal4=261.44/4)
"bal5="
(bal5=261.45/5)
"bal6="
(bal6=261.46/6)
"bal7="
(bal7=261.48/7)
"bal8="
(bal8=261.49/8)
"bal9="
(bal9=261.52/9)
"bal10="
(bal10=261.54/10)
(bal1/(bal1+bal2+bal3+bal4+bal5+bal6+bal7+bal8+bal9+bal10))
```

All of that is run through `bc` which prints something like:

```
bal1=261.40
bal2=130.70
bal3=87.14
bal4=65.36
bal5=52.29
bal6=43.57
bal7=37.35
bal8=32.68
bal9=29.05
bal10=26.15
.34
```

If you can be clearer about your input and output I can help to more specifically tailor this to your needs - but doing `var=$(echo stuff at | bc)` once per iteration is wasteful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually what I've written as _"node$i getbalance"_ is in reality _"bitcoin-cli -datadir=""$DATADIR"/node$i/" getbalance"_ ..I've created directories for each Bitcoin daemon instance it start _from_ (there are config-files in directories) and would like to do some calculations with the float type output of my command.

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi - right, I know it wasn't `$#` in your code, because your iterator was `$i`. But in this one it's `$#`. I usually like to let the shell do the count implicitly - as I do with `$#` - rather than insist on doing the adding myself. So that's a directory?  What are the extra `""` for? And can you quote me a typical line of output for a single call to `"node$i" getbalance`?

Comment: Oh I see, now I'm learning some new stuff, thanks!..Extra `""` were only to distinguish code from comment text, nothing important actually..A typical balance output is just something like `123.00000000`.

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi Oh, cool. That's easier.